# Count user views (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

How do I count user views?

For example, a user opened an app and got +1 view.

With each next opening of the application, 1 view will be added. and so on endlessly up to 100-200-300 and so on

[image: image1]

Image number one, zero views
But when the user opens the app twice, there will be two views. Each new discovery will add plus one viewing

[image: image2]

If the user has opened the application a hundred times, then a hundred views will already be displayed

[image: image3]

**Here is my code**:

```
struct views: View {
   var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                
                Image(systemName: "eye")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text("0")
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .padding(.leading)
                
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 150)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

**Help me please, I'm new to swift, I will be grateful for any your help, thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@AppStorage` to store the view count (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper).

To tell when the application has become active and add to the counter, you can use `@Environment(\.scenePhase)` (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-when-your-app-moves-to-the-background-or-foreground-with-scenephase).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("userViews") private var userViews = 0
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "eye")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                Text("\(userViews)")
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .padding(.leading)
                
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 150)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            if newPhase == .active {
                userViews += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will other users see these views?

Comment: No -- this is for storage on one device -- that seemed to be what your question was asking. If you need a server to store it on, this is a *much* bigger question. I'd look into Firebase for this type of thing. The mechanics of using the Environment scene phase will be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much!) Do you know how to make these views saved and seen by other users?

Comment: Yes -- please see the above comment. Investigate using Firebase for a server backend. They have great tutorials in their documentation.

Comment: I'm familiar with Firebase, but I'm new to swift, I'm not sure what I can do (

Comment: Have you read their documentation?

Comment: yes, but I do not understand how to implement this in my application

Comment: Okay. You should probably start a new question with the extent of your attempt and where you got stuck. The documentation is pretty good, so it would be pointless for someone to just recreate it unless they knew the specific point where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I need the same as in my question about views, only that these views are seen by all users and not one user

Comment: Right -- you said "I do not understand how to implement this in my application" regarding Firebase, but you haven't shown the extent of your attempt or where the documentation failed to provide enough information for you. Without that information, it would be difficult if not impossible to provide a satisfying answer to your new question.

Comment: you understand what I need, I'm studying the firebase documentation now, and I'm trying to understand what I need to do, you understand the essence of my question, I want the prosotras to be in real time so that they are displayed for all users of the application.

Comment: I understand. Add Firebase to your application, including either Firestore or the Realtime Database. The documentation will show you how to integrate it. Then, you'll want to use the same technique I showed you in your original question using `@Environment(\.scenePhase)` to trigger a write to Firebase. That's a lot to get started with -- if you get stuck doing that, I'd suggest opening a new question with how far you got and where you got stuck.

Comment: Note that I'm saying "new question" because your original question didn't mention anything about multiple users and in fact was pretty explicit about one user ("If the user has opened the application a hundred times, then a hundred views will already be displayed")

Comment: ok, I understand you, thanks, I will create a new question, and I hope they will help me, I am new to programming, and I want to know how to implement this